# JQUERY Animate with textShadow css3

Tags: jquery, css

i try to make a css3 animation based on the blury ex here : http://www.alexpeattie.com/projects/animate-textshadow/

But i cant make it works :

```
$(function(){

  $(".t").hover(function() { 
    $(this).animate({textShadow: "#fff 0 0 10px"});
}, function() { 
    $(this).animate({textShadow: "#fff 0 0 0px"});
});

});
```

Any idea ?

The result online is here : http://sowuz.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many comments on the project page saying that `jquery.animate-textshadow.js` does not work with jQuery 1.8.x.  From the website:

> Does not work with jQuery 1.8, what it needs to be changed in order to
>   work?
>
> Does not work with jQuery 1.8

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCE3j/1/) is an example of your code working with jQuery 1.7.2, but it does not work in jQuery 1.8.2.

Comment: @Anthony It appears to work for me in jQuery 1.7.2, but not 1.8.x: http://jsfiddle.net/wCE3j/